# Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, pip

I've created folder and initialized a virtualenv instance in it.

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv env
```

When I run `(env)$ pip freeze`, it shows the installed packages as it should.

Now I want to rename `myproject/` to `project/`.

```
$ mv myproject/ project/
```

However, now when I run

```
$ . env/bin/activate
(env)$ pip freeze
```

it says pip is not installed. How do I rename the project folder without breaking the environment?

Comment: This question is old and already has an answer, but I have to wonder, why couldn't the OP just move the virtualenv back to where it was? Obviously that doesn't solve the desire to move / rename, but wouldn't that restore a working virtualenv, or is it already hopelessly broken?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would repair the virtual env, but not solve the issue.

Comment: November 2019, Python3.  The best solution for me is describe in https://aarongorka.com/blog/portable-virtualenv/

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You need to adjust your install to use relative paths. `virtualenv` provides for this with the `--relocatable` option. From [the docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable):

> Normally environments are tied to a
>   specific path. That means that you
>   cannot move an environment around or
>   copy it to another computer. You can
>   fix up an environment to make it
>   relocatable with the command:
>
> $ virtualenv --relocatable ENV
>
> **NOTE:** ENV is the name of the virtual environment and you must run this from outside the ENV directory.
>
> This will make some of the files
>   created by setuptools or distribute
>   use relative paths, and will change
>   all the scripts to use
>   activate_this.py instead of using the
>   location of the Python interpreter to
>   select the environment.
>
> Note: you must run this after you've
>   installed any packages into the
>   environment. If you make an
>   environment relocatable, then install
>   a new package, you must run virtualenv
>   --relocatable again.

Comment: caveat: Changing an env to relocatable does more than just let you move the folder. (see the *Note:* copied from the docs)... it may have side effects.

Comment: The --relocatable option currently has a number of issues, and is not guaranteed to work in all circumstances. It is possible that the option will be deprecated in a future version of virtualenv. Also, this does not make your packages cross-platform. You can move the directory around, but it can only be used on other similar computers.

Comment: @TheDemz `grep -EIr '\Wold_venv_name\W' /path/to/new_venv` will help find any shabangs that use the old venv, but is not a complete verifcation of the relocated venv.

Comment: Also, you'll have to edit the virtualenvwrapper `.project` file, which contains the path to the source code that depends on the virtualenv, assuming you are using virutalenvwrapper and have also renamed the project dir to match the new virtualenv.

Comment: I had to deactivate the virtualenv before running this.

Comment: This feature is now deprecated. This answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 136):

I believe *"knowing why" matters more than "knowing how"*. So, here is another approach to fix this.

When you run `. env/bin/activate`, it actually executes the following commands (using `/tmp` for example):

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/tmp/myproject/env"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

However, you have just renamed `myproject` to `project`, so that command failed to execute.
That is why it says `pip is not installed`, because you haven't installed `pip` in the system global environment and your virtualenv `pip` is not sourced correctly.

If you want to fix this manually, this is the way:

1. With your favorite editor like Vim, modify `/tmp/project/env/bin/activate` usually in line 42:

   `VIRTUAL_ENV='/tmp/myproject/env'` => `VIRTUAL_ENV='/tmp/project/env'`
2. Modify `/tmp/project/env/bin/pip` in line 1:

   `#!/tmp/myproject/env/bin/python` => `#!/tmp/project/env/bin/python`

After that, activate your virtual environment `env` again, and you will see your `pip` has come back again.

Comment: If manually changing the paths is desired, then it should be noted that there are more than two hard-coded files. Find them all with something like: `grep -iHnR venv-name /path/to/venv-name | grep -v "^Binary file" | grep -i venv-name`. In fact, I noticed that in one of my Django instances, a lot of the packages had the "path to Python sh-bang" in them.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I definitely needed to know why... Thanks!

Comment: In contrast to Keven's comment above, I find that editing these two lines solves all problems for me with regards to moving `virtualenv`'s. Perhaps there's some use case that I'm not using and so don't encounter the problem.

Comment: Scratch that! Today I ran into a problem: ipython would not work within the `virtualenv`. To solve it, I edited the bash header (what is it called?) in the `ipython` file and then it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm this is not working for me, and it seems my activate script does not have the Line 1 that is referred to here in Step 2. Did something change?

Comment: Wouldn't this entire problem be eliminated by setting `VIRTUAL_ENV=\`pwd\`` ?

Comment: @Homunculus No. Think about what would happen if you activated the virtualenv from another directory.

Comment: Any idea why they used an absolute path instead of a relative one? Something like using %~dp0 to get the parent directory of the bat file on Windows would surely make this better?

Comment: @matt.baker Python infrastructure is full of half broken designs like this. They probably just didn't think about it.

Answer (score 43):

**NOTE:** As @jb. points out, this solution only applies to easily (re)created `virtualenv`s. If an environment takes several hours to install this solution is not recommended

---

Virtualenvs are great because they are easy to make and switch around; they keep you from getting locked into a single configuration. If you know the project requirements, or can get them, **Make a new `virtualenv`**:

- Create a `requirements.txt` file

  `(env)$ pip freeze > requirements.txt`

  - If you can't create the `requirements.txt` file, check `env/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` before removing the original `env`.
- Delete the existing `(env)`

  `deactivate && rm -rf env`
- Create a new `virtualenv`, activate it, and install requirements

  `virtualenv env && . env/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt`

---

Alternatively, use virtualenvwrapper to make things a little easier as all virtualenvs are kept in a centralized location

```
$(old-venv) pip freeze > temp-reqs.txt
$(old-venv) deactivate
$ mkvirtualenv new-venv
$(new-venv) pip install -r temp-reqs.txt
$(new-venv) rmvirtualenv old-venv
```

Comment: Well for some people `pip install -r requirements.txt` takes couple of hours (compiling third party C-extensions on raspberry pi).

Comment: Perhaps true, but that seems like an edge-case to me. I still think this may be a viable solution for many cases.

Comment: Yah, many projects (Django website, for example) only take 30 seconds to install everything, even if they have a couple of dozen dependencies (provided you download everything first and use '--no-index --find-links=downloadDir')

Comment: To delete a python virtual environment I suggest using rmvirtualenv.

Comment: Good point. That's how I do it. I think that's covered in the second part of the answer. It seemed the OP wasn't using `virtualenvwrapper` so the main answer is only focused on `virtualenv`

Comment: @bnjmn the one-liner `virtualenv env && pip install -r requirements.txt` will NOT install the requirements in the new environment because you don't activate it

Comment: @Yarin Thanks for pointing that out. I totally missed it, being `virtualenv-wrapper` user myself (which auto activates on creation). I've update my answer to include activating the `virtualenv` in hopes of avoiding any confusion.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the origin question: how to move the venv dir without breaking it

Answer (score 29):

I always install virtualenvwrapper to help out. From the shell prompt:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

There is a way documented in the virtualenvwrapper documents - [cpvirtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=cpvirtualenv#cpvirtualenv)
This is what you do. Make sure you are out of your environment and back to the shell prompt. Type in this with the names required:

```
cpvirtualenv oldenv newenv
```

And then, if necessary:

```
rmvirtualenv oldenv
```

To go to your newenv:

```
workon newenv
```

Comment: Afrowave's answer really should be the accepted method.

Comment: This only works if one is using `virtualenvwrapper`, not just `virtualenv`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29482481/543738) from @ryankdwyer is better.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that one should install 'virtualenvwrapper'. Assuming that the renaming virtual environments happens a lot, I would recommend this way.

Comment: Even though it relies on virtualenvwrapper, it is the simplest one. And it works well.

Answer (score 19):

You can fix your issue by following these steps:

1. rename your directory
2. rerun this: `$ virtualenv ..\path\renamed_directory`
3. virtualenv will correct the directory associations while leaving your packages in place
4. `$ scripts/activate`
5. `$ pip freeze` to verify your packages are in place
6. An important caveat, if you have any static path dependencies in script files in your virtualenv directory, you will have to manually change those.

Comment: This was a very good solution for me.  Since this solution _may_ avoid some of the problems associated with `--relocatable`, I think this solution is better than the accepted answer.  So far, I've noticed that many `.pyc` files in `_new_name_/lib/python2.7` still refer to `_old_name_`.  However, that doesn't seem to affect how my environment works. Maybe the only better solution is using `virtualenvwrapper` or some of the other utilities mentioned among the answers here.  At least this solution doesn't require installing additional programs.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

Yet another way to do it that worked for me many times without problems is [virtualenv-clone](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv-clone):

```
pip install virtualenv-clone
virtualenv-clone old-dir/env new-dir/env
```

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer. Hands down! It took some time to clone, so have patience guys.

Comment: virtualenv-clone neglects to update the prompt. Had to go in an do that manually. Other than that, it's great.

Answer (score 10):

Run this inside your project folder:

```
cd bin
sed -i 's/old_dir_name/new_dir_name/g' *
```

Don't forget to deactivate and activate.

Comment: Works well; Or for Linux path: `sed -i "s|$old_dir|$new_dir|g" bin/*`

Comment: `sed -i '.original' 's/old_dir_name/new_dir_name/g' *` for macs

Comment: @Alex Or `sed -i '' 's/old_dir_name/new_dir_name/g' *` if you don't want to create any backup files.

Answer (score 2):

### In Python 3.3+ with built-in venv

As of Python 3.3 the `virtualenv` package is now built-in to Python as the `venv` module. There are a few minor differences, one of which is the `--relocatable` option has been removed. As a result, it is normally best to recreate a virtual environment rather than attempt to move it. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772116/6501141) for more information on how to do that.

What is the purpose behind wanting to move rather than just recreate any virtual environment? A virtual environment is intended to manage the dependencies of a module/package with the venv so that it can have different and specific versions of a given package or module it is dependent on, and allow a location for those things to be installed locally.

As a result, a package should provide a way to recreate the venv from scratch. Typically this is done with a `requirements.txt` file and sometimes also a `requirements-dev.txt` file, and even a script to recreate the venv in the setup/install of the package itself.

One part that may give headaches is that you may need a particular version of Python as the executable, which is difficult to automate, if not already present. However, when recreating an existing virtual environment, one can simply run python from the existing venv when creating the new one. After that it is typically just a matter of using pip to reinstall all dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file:

From Git Bash on Windows:

```sh
python -m venv mynewvenv
source myvenv/Scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It can get a bit more involved if you have several local dependencies from other locally developed packages, because you may need to update local absolute paths, etc. - though if you set them up as proper Python packages, you can install from a git repo, and thus avoid this issue by having a static URL as the source.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv --relocatable ENV` is not a desirable solution. I assume most people want the ability to rename a virtualenv *without* any long-term side effects.

So I've created a simple tool to do just that. The project page for [virtualenv-mv](https://github.com/brbsix/virtualenv-mv) outlines it in a bit more detail, but essentially you can use `virtualenv-mv` just like you'd use a simple implementation of `mv` (without any options).

**For example:**

```
virtualenv-mv myproject project
```

Please note however that I just hacked this up. It could break under unusual circumstances (e.g. symlinked virtualenvs) so please be careful (back up what you can't afford to lose) and let me know if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier solution which worked for me: just copy the `site-packages` folder of your old virtual environment into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio Code (vscode), I just opened the ./env folder in my project root, and did a bulk find/replace to switch to my updated project name. This resolved the issue.

Confirm with `which python`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an conda env,

```
conda create --name new_name --clone old_name
conda remove --name old_name --all # or its alias: `conda env remove --name old_name`
```