# How to migrate virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv

I have a relatively big project that has many dependencies, and I would like to distribute this project around, but installing these dependencies where a bit of a pain, and takes a very long time (pip install takes quite some time). So I was wondering if it was possible to migrate a whole virtualenv to another machine and have it running.

I tried copying the whole virtualenv, but whenever I try running something, this virtualenv still uses the path of my old machine. For instance when I run

```
source activate
pserve development.ini
```

I get

```
bash: ../bin/pserve: /home/sshum/backend/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This is my old directory. So is there a way to have virtualenv reconfigure this path with a new path?

I tried `sed -i 's/sshum/dev1/g' *` in the bin directory and it solved that issue. However, I'm getting a different issue now, my guess is that this sed changed something.

I've confirmed that I have `libssl-dev` installed but when I run `python` I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libssl.so.1.0.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libssl.so.1.0.0'
```

But when I run `aptitude search libssl` and I see:

```
i A libssl-dev        - SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
```

I also tried `virtualenv --relocatable backend` but no go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it)

Answer (score 2):

Export virtualenvironment

*from within the virtual environment:*

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

as example, here is for myproject virtual environment: 
[image]

once in the new machine & environment, copy the requirements.txt into the *new project folder in the new machine* and run the terminal command:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then you should have all the packages previously available in the old virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

The clean way seems to be with `virtualenv --relocatable`.

Alternatively, you can do it manually by editing the `VIRTUAL_ENV` path in `bin/activate` to reflect the changes. If you choose to do so, you must also edit the first line (#) of `bin/pserve` which indicates the interpreter path.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new virtualenv it is configured for the computer it is running on. I even think that it is configured for that specific directory it is created in. So I think you should always create a fresh virtualenv when you move you code. What might work is copying the lib/Pythonx.x/site-packages in your virtualenv directory, but I don't think that is a particularly good solution.

What may be a better solution is using the pip download cache. This will at least speed up the download part of pip install. Have a look at this thread: [How do I install from a local cache with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip)

Comment: Yea, that's what I've resorted to. Thanks