# Are python 3.x venv environments relocatable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

As of python 3.3 the stdlib has the venv module for creating virtual environments.
Are python 3.x venv environments relocatable?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [python - Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it) ?

Comment: @user202729 virtualenv package and the python3 venv package are not the same and as such this question stands on its own

Answer (score 6):

Nope, commands installed in `./bin` have fixed paths in shabang lines.

Comment: so it's portable if you don't care about `./bin` (the only thing you should be calling from that in the first place is `python3` anyhow)