# Why is Jupyter notebook 'pointing' at old repo location?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've recently moved the location of my git repo. All my standard Python scripts work just fine but for some reason my Jupyter notebooks can't even import any modules. I've re-cloned my repo to the original location and the notebooks run fine again.

I've tried searching the VS Code settings for something that resembles a working directory for Jupyter but no luck. Any ideas on what might be going on and how I could fix it?

For reference:

- OS: Windows 10
- VS Code: 1.53.2
- Python extension: 2021.1.502429796
- Jupyter extension: 2020.12.414227025

---

**Edit:**

I've been able to put a sticking plaster on this by using `os.chdir()` to select the new repo.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment? (this definitely doesn't contain a [example], as far as I can see)

Comment: Afraid I've got no idea how to produce an MRE for this sort of thing. What should I include?

Comment: Something like "create a git repo with `mkdir A; cd A; git init`, create a jupyter notebook in A, `cd A; mkvenv X`, execute `mv A B`, open the jupyter notebook, etc.)

Comment: Although if you do have a virtual environment then that's obviously the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186207/are-python-3-x-venv-environments-relocatable

Comment: Thanks. Does a virtual environment control the working directory? Not sure this can be the issue as my normal Python scripts run fine from the same virtual environment as the one Jupyter is using.

Comment: Can't tell without a [example].