# Caching virtual environment for gitlab-ci

Tags: python-3.x, caching, pip, conda, gitlab-ci

I cached Pip packages using a Gitlab CI script, so that's not an issue.

Now I also want to catch a Conda virtual environment, because it reduces time to setup the environment.

I cached a virtual environment. Unfortunately it takes a long time at the end to cache all the venv files.

I tried to cache only the `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages` folder and it seems to reduce run time of the pipe.

My question is: am I doing it correctly?

The script is given below:

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: continuumio/miniconda3:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - .pip
    - ls -l $CI_PROJECT_DIR/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

before_script:
  - chmod +x gitlab-ci.sh
  - ./gitlab-ci.sh

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python eval.py
```

gitlab-ci.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ENV_NAME=myenv
ENV_REQUIREMENTS=requirements.txt

if [ ! -d $ENV_NAME ]; then
    echo "Environment $ENV_NAME does not exist. Creating it now!"
    conda create --path --prefix "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/$ENV_NAME"
fi

echo "Activating environment: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$ENV_NAME"
source activate "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/$ENV_NAME"

echo "Installing PIP"
conda install -y pip

echo "PIP: installing required packages"
echo `which pip`
pip --cache-dir=.pip install -r "$ENV_REQUIREMENTS"
```

Answer (score 7):

Reusing pip cache between builds is a very good idea but doing the same for the virtualenvs is a really bad idea.

This is because virtualenv can easily become messed in a way that you cannot really detect at runtime. This not only happens, it happens more often than you could imagine and for that reason please avoid it.

PS. Advise from someone that learnt that the hard way.

Comment: Could you give more details in which way it could become messed?

Comment: @sorin - it's possible you could be correct, however `gitlab` OFFICIAL docs contradict your answer.  Your answer needs explanation or downvotes. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-python-dependencies

Comment: Actually, GitLab docs have been updated to [recommend exactly this approach](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-python-dependencies).

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep to comment on @sorin's answer, but we're running into the same issue right now with a current GitLab (14.6).

We have four jobs, all using the same base Docker image. In one, we set up a virtualenv and then cache it; the other 3 jobs pull the cache, activate the venv, then try to use it. Those 3 jobs often fail, as they are unable to find the right python or load particular modules from the activated venv.

The problem with `virtualenv` is that (at least as of the venv module in Python 3.3) virtualenvs are not relocatable. The `activate` script contains the absolute path to the virtualenv in a `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable. GitLab runners by default include the unique runner token as part of the [build directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/best_practice/#build-directory), which then becomes part of that `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable. So if you cache the virtualenv on one runner, then try to use it on another runner, it will fail because the paths don't match. `activate` won't even warn you that the `VIRTUAL_ENV` path doesn't exist.

If you have one GitLab runner, you're probably OK. If not, you can write scripts to update a virtualenv yourself, which may or may not work well (see [Can I move a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv)). Or do the safe thing and recreate the venv in every job; you *can* get away with caching the pip cache, at least.

Answer (score 3):

We are successfully using the method outlined in the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-python-dependencies

```
# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/
```

There may be other things missing, but your first pass probably misses:

- when reducing size of the whole `.../venv/` directory tree, you probably need `.../venv/bin` as this is required to find the correct python version; see this locally after `activate`ing your `venv` with the command `which -a python3`
- if pip will be used again (such as later in your build via some make recipe) you need to move the `pip` cache as shown above.