# Reinstalled my environment and virtualenv not working like previously

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was having some problems with my environment so I reinstalled homebrew, python 3, and reset my $PATH. Now that I'm trying to pick up where I left off, I noticed that virtualenv isn't working like it had previously. When I run `python3 -m venv ~/.venv/proj1` I get the following output

> Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/johnsmith/.venv/proj1/bin/python3': '/Users/johnsmith/.venv/proj1/bin/python3'.

This command was working fine prior to resetting everything. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: You need to create your `virtualenv` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rm -rf ~/.venv
```

and then recreate the venv

Comment: Tried doing that but I get a bunch of lines saying permission denied

Comment: Whats the reason for removing venv?

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: Virtual environments are disposable by design. If your current venv has issues, the first diagnostic step should be to recreate it. 99% of the time, that will fix the issue.

Comment: Your solution worked but I'm a little confused about whats going on. When I run `python3 -m venv ~/.venv/proj1` I'm creating a virtual environment called proj1, right?

Comment: Yes, and then you activate that environment for that project. You could also install the venv in the project's folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the virtualenv, see this post: [Can I move a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv/32408679)

Essentially you can just use `mv` as usual and the run `sed -i -e 's|username/first|username/second|' my-venv/bin/activate` (substitute the old location for username/first and the new location for username/second).