# After activate a python virtual environment, typing `python` still get me the version in PATH

Tags: python, python-venv, virtual-environment

I am using windows 7. I have multiple python virtual environments. Say I added `venv_1` to system PATH. In the command line, say I activate another `venv_2`, now the prompt line shows

```
(venv_2) C:\>
```

But if I type `python` here, it still runs the python in `venv_1`.

Is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the intended behaviour, but it probably means you either made a mistake in setting up the virtual environment, or in activating it.

To be sure what version is being run, try running:

```
where python
```

Whatever the top item in the resulting list is, will be the copy of Python Windows would start. If you're right and it does actually point to `venv_1`, then there must be something wrong with the setup in `venv_2`.

By running `set`, you should be able to see a list of all environment variables. Check for:

```
PATH=<long list of directory names, it should have the venv_2\Scripts at the start>
```

And:

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=<the same list, without that entry>
```

It's this simple change to the path that causes Windows to find the Python in your virtual environment first, before the one in your other virtual environment, that you added to the global path.

Note that adding the Scripts folder of the one virtual environment probably isn't a good idea, since you'd only want to use that when the corresponding virtual environment is activated and all the environment variables set accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Following your procedure, I found the problem. I changed the path of `venv_2` before. with `set`, the `PATH` still shows the old path to `venv_2`. After looking around I realize venv's can't really be relocated (hmmm...). I guess I will just re-create the venv.

Comment: You can move a virtual environment, but it takes some extra work. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv - note that in most cases it won't be worth it. Recreating the venv and just quickly reinstalling packages using something like `pip install -r requirements.txt` after a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` tends to be a lot easier and quicker.

Comment: Yes, I found out about `--relocatable`, and that it is experimental. I end up just re-create my venv. However some packages are not on PyPI, and they require a specific installation order, so I had to do it manually. In the requirements is there a way to tell pip to install a local `whl`?