# flask run command fail after folder location change

Tags: python, flask

I changed the location and changed name of my flask folder, which contains a virtual envrionment.

```
flask run
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\previous\path\backend_flask\.venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\current\path\flask_backend\.venv\Scripts\flask.exe" run': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However,

```
python -m flask run
```

still works.

Here is my project structure. `.venv` folder is a neighbor of `app` folder.

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── database.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
├── output.txt
└── main.py
```

How can I fix the error from the `flask run` command?

Comment: @jsotola I want to know what caused the error message and how to fix the error.

Comment: Can you share your current folder structure?

Comment: yes @RicardoSanchez

Comment: In your Scripts/activate and Scripts/activate.bat file, try replacing VIRTUAL_ENV=/old/path to VIRTUAL_ENV=/new/path. I tried to replicate your problem but couldn't do it, but I've definitely run into something like this before.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv/58772116#58772116), there is no clean way to relocate a virtual environment. The flask is installed in the virtual environment and when I run `flask run`, the virtual environment files cannot find the executables because of the relocation. The same problem occurs if I run `pip` with virtual environment activated.

Python 3.9

I summaries the solution here, this works regardless whether or not you have relocated. (in my case I am able to `freeze` with `python -m pip freeze` even though `pip freeze` doesn't work).

1. activate your virtual environment.
2. `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt` to record your current dependencies. Make sure it records the environment in your virtual environment instead of your local environment. (make sure you activate virtual venv before freeze).
3. deactivate your virtual environment.
4. remove your current virtual environment folder. `rm -r <folder name>`
5. in the new location, install virtual env: `python -m venv <name of env>`
6. activate the new virtual env
7. reinstall the dependencies from the `requirement` file you just created:
   `python -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt`