# Python venv from Linux is missing Windows Scripts

Tags: python, python-venv

I am cloning a project's venv directory to my Windows environment. The virtual env was created on a Linux box. As a result, I guess, it doesn't include the Scripts\Activate script. The Scripts\ folder is completely empty.

What do I need to do to Activate the environment (so I can use it in Visual Studio Code)?

Edit: Apparently I got the venv paradigm wrong. You don't share the venv, but only the requirements.txt and allow each dev to create their venv (or not, if they choose). Thanks @bck and @Santiago

Comment: Why do you copy venv?

Comment: Virtual environments should remaking on every device. They're working different on every OS. For solving your problem just remove old environment and remake by documentation.

Comment: It's not best practices to clone the venv for a project. If it has a requerirements.txt you should be able to create a venv and replicate the environment. On the other side, more info is info about your setup

Comment: We're experimenting with virtual environments. Isn't the point of having one that you can share the packages with all devs so they don't have to install everything in global?

Comment: My project code is stored in the venv\myproject directory. Should we not have done that?

Comment: No, just every developer should make virtual environment on her PC and install all requirements.

Comment: @StephanB Indeed you are sharing your `requirements.txt` file with other devs, not the whole environment. Would it be efficient if you shared `node_modules` every time ? [Can I move a virtualenv ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv)

Comment: Our initial idea was that, by synchronizing our venv, our prod environment will automatically get any packages we update in the venv repo because it resyncs every few minutes automatically. Any thoughts on that aspect of it?

Comment: @StephanB Update the `requirements.txt`. Thus, when your system detects a change in the file, it should update the virtual environment accordingly.

Comment: Does python have any internal tricks to automate that, or do I need to write an external script for that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I got the venv paradigm wrong. You don't share the venv, but only the requirements.txt and allow each dev to create their venv (or not, if they choose). Thanks @bck and @Santiago