# Poetry `FileNotFoundError` when using cached venv in CI build

Tags: python-poetry

I'm trying to optimize our **poetry build times** by storing a *tar.gz* of the venv on the end of the build in an azure storage blob *(an S3)* with key generated by doing a `md5sum` of the `poetry.lock` and the `pyproject.toml`. *(this works fine)*

So, in the beginning of another build, I would hash those files and try to find if that blob exists in storage. If yes, download it and extract its contents to the `.venv/` dir of the project.

This worked fine at the beginning but after a while I started getting builds that were throwing this error when trying to run a command through poetry: *(any command)*

```
+ poetry run reorder-python-imports --diff-only <SOME_FILES>

  FileNotFoundError

  [Errno 2] No such file or directory

  at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py:591 in _execvpe
       587│         argrest = (args,)
       588│         env = environ
       589│ 
       590│     if path.dirname(file):
    →  591│         exec_func(file, *argrest)
       592│         return
       593│     saved_exc = None
       594│     path_list = get_exec_path(env)
       595│     if name != 'nt':
```

I have confirmed that there is no `.venv` folder already in the project dir and that the contents are exactly the same as if it were going to install it from the network.

If I just run `poetry install` on top of the cached venv, it says it has no more dependencies to install, but it throws the error above.
If I delete the venv and install everything again, commands work fine.

I have no more ideas on how to debug and solve this issue. Help would be very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've understood that virtualenvs have some hardcoded paths that are not easy to move around.

For what it says in this post [Can I move a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv) we should not move venvs as a good practice.

And there it goes my way of speeding up builds...

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem. You said "we should not move venvs as a good practice", but are you really moving them? Aren't you just zipping and unzipping to the exact same place?

Comment: In my case I noticed that after recreating it from scratch, I got different values for `version_info` and `virtualenv` in `.venv/pyenv.cfg`. This is probably because I tried to reuse the cache after upgrading python from 3.9.13 to 3.9.14.