# How to enlarge a project by parent directory and move venv

Tags: python, pycharm

Let's say I have a project in pycharm with structure like this:

[image]

With venv inside of this project. Now I want to expand the project with  a parent folder such that integrator is a subfolder of the main folder and move venv to the parent folder so I can use it across the whole project. How to do this in pycharm?\

Maybe the solution: Copy the venv folder ---> paste it in parent directory ---> delete venv in integrator folder ----> create a new project with venv ?

Comment: Move your venv directory to where ever you want, and then edit interpreter settings to point your new venv folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I move a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv)