# venv dependencies are being added without being downloading

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I use virtual environments in my django projects. When I create my venv, I do like this from my command line

```
cd Dev
python3 -m venv <name of venv>
```

This creates a folder called venv on my mac machine in my Dev folder.

After I pip install django in the venv, I use the `pip list` command. At this point the list only contains the default django packages. It looks like this for example:

```
asgiref    3.5.2
Django     4.0.6
pip        22.0.4
setuptools 58.1.0
sqlparse   0.4.2
```

Then I start my django project like this.

```
django-admin startproject <name of project>
```

After that when I move the venv folder inside my main project folder, and run `pip list` again, all dependencies from previous projects are being added to the list. Now it looks like this

```
asgiref             3.4.1
boto3               1.24.12
botocore            1.27.12
certifi             2022.5.18.1
charset-normalizer  2.0.12
Django              4.0.5
django-cors-headers 3.13.0
django-dotenv       1.4.2
django-embed-video  1.4.4
django-filter       21.1
django-htmx         1.9.0
django-js-asset     2.0.0
django-mathfilters  1.0.0
django-storages     1.12.3
djangorestframework 3.13.1
gunicorn            20.1.0
idna                3.3
jmespath            1.0.1
Pillow              9.1.1
pip                 22.1.2
psycopg2            2.9.3
psycopg2-binary     2.9.3
python-dateutil     2.8.2
pytz                2022.1
requests            2.28.0
s3transfer          0.6.0
setuptools          58.1.0
six                 1.16.0
sqlparse            0.4.2
urllib3             1.26.9
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Show us the exact commands to reproduce incl. the relevant output!

Comment: Please show how you are creating the virtual environment...

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: `when I move the venv folder inside my main project folder` [You should never do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv), it should be the source of problem (although I don't understand the reason of this odd `list` behavior). Probably your previous project venv is on PATH somehow.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, then where should I store the venv?

Comment: Personally I have Django installed in system site-packages (as well as linters - black, pre-commit, isort) and create venv only after project creation. If you for some reason extremely dislike such way or need outdated Django version - create venv, install Django, remove venv, create new venv in new directory, install again. But this is an opinion-based question now.

Comment: And to answer your question on odd `list` output, could you check `which python` before and after venv moving and show your `PATH`?

Comment: Before the path is `/Dev/venv/bin/python` and after it is `/usr/bin/python`. I have also noticed that if I run `pip list` outside any venv, I also get the long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't move your virtual environment after creation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407365/can-i-move-a-virtualenv) for motivation and explanation. You can install Django on system level and create environment only when project directory already exists to avoid this moving.

And here's why your environment stops working after moving. Suppose (`/` for simplicity) you have `/myenv` environment path, then after `. activate` your path looks like

```
PATH="/myenv/bin:<other entries>:/usr/bin:<...>"
```

Now `python` resolves to (`which python`) `/myenv/bin/python`.

Then you move your environment. `PATH` remains unchanged, but now there is no `/myenv/bin` directory, so `python` resolves to `/usr/bin/python` and `pip` to `/usr/bin/pip`. The fact that now `pip` has many packages available means that you have installed dependencies for your previous project system-wide (maybe accidentally, forgotten to activate venv). You can confirm it using `pip` without active venv.