# !source venv/bin/activate not working in a Kaggle notebook any ideas?

Tags: python, conda, kaggle

I generated venv with below command

```
!python3 -m venv venv
```

Activated it with below command

```
!source venv/bin/activate
```

But it is not working. How do I know?

When I do `!pip freeze` it shows the entire notebook not the activated `venv`

Any ideas?

Here how do I test screenshot

[image]

Comment: @JohnGordon when I do pip freeze I am supposed to see information about the new venv. But it is showing entire notebook.

Comment: I think you have to create the venv and activate it **before** starting the notebook.

Comment: @JohnGordon how is that even possible? Without starting the session you can't make any install edit etc. This is an empty notebook session.

Comment: I don't know kaggle and am interested in the answer. I noticed at https://www.kaggle.com/docs/notebooks _Notebook Versions and Containers_ that it seems like you create versions and snapshots in kaggle. I didn't see anything about pip and kaggle. Just because you can run a command doesn't mean that it does something that can rebuild a kaggle environment.

Comment: @tdelaney it gives you a python runtime. we are not rebuilding environment or anything. this is simple python stuff or i know wrong? it is generating the venv but activate is the problematic part

Comment: Are you running kaggle on your local machine, or as a cloud-hosted IDE?

Comment: @JohnGordon kaggle is a cloud provider like google colab. i am using free version.

Answer (score 1):

Each `!` command is executed in a subshell which exits immediately.
For example, `!cd` doesn't work, we have to use `%cd`. ([docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html#directory-management))

So `!source activate` & `!pip freeze` are executed in different env.
Try `!source activate && pip freeze`.

Not very related, there's another pitfall: [venv is hard to relocate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408679/).
The path is hard-coded in the `activate` file.
And it fails silently when the path doesn't exist.

Comment: You can strengthen the "I think" -- this is fact, not mere supposition.

Comment: Edited. Added IPython docs.