# Error when starting ipython notebook when into virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

When I type ipython notebook it works fine. However I need to work into a virtual environment:

What I do

```
virtualenv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now I type

```
ipython notebook
```

This given the error:

```
/home/derk/assignment2/.env/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So when not in the virtual environment I can start the notebook. However, when not into the virtual environment it gives an error.

The requirements.txt looks like this:

```
Cython==0.21.2
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.7.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==14.05.14
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==2.3.1
matplotlib==1.4.2
mock==1.0.1
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.9.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.0
pytz==2014.10
pyzmq==14.4.1
scipy==0.14.1
six==1.9.0
tornado==4.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Everything worked correctly before, but now (maybe after some software updates) it doesnot. I tried reinstalling Anaconda (as suggested on some sites), but without success. What could be the problem here?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /home/derk/assignment2/.env/bin/python`?

Comment: Output: -rwxrwxr-x 1 derk derk 3345416 nov  1 15:47 /home/derk/cs231n/assignment2/.env/bin/python

Comment: I notice now I moved the notebooks to another folder /home/derk/cs231n/assignment2 instead of /home/derk/assignment2. Why is it now going wrong?

Comment: You cannot simply move a virtualenv. Instead create a new one at the desired location and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when one has moved or renamed the `virtualenv`. In my case, the folder was moved to another user(`mint` -> `emil`), but otherwise had the same path. To solve it one can edit the configuration files, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683703/3980197). In my case, python worked fine within the `virtualenv`, but `ipython` did not:

```
(env) emil@emil-VirtualBox ~/X/X $ ipython
bash: /home/emil/X/env/bin/ipython: /home/mint/X/env/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Checking which file was run:

```
(env) emil@emil-VirtualBox ~/X/env/bin $ which ipython
/home/emil/X/env/bin/ipython
```

Did not indicate a problem. I browsed into the folder and the file was there. So it wasn't missing. Then I remembered that I had had to edit some files after moving the `virtualenv` earlier. One has to edit the 'bash header' ([sha-bang](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html)) in all the important files. In my case, these were:

```
activate
pip
ipython
```

I.e., find the header which looks like:

```
#!/home/mint/X/env/bin/python3.5
```

and change to:

```
#!/home/emil/X/env/bin/python3.5
```