# virtualenv uses the wrong python version despite the correct one being in the directory

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I looked at the previous questions on this topic, but they don't seem to cover this odd issue.

I had a 2.7.x based `virtualenv` at `~/GP` for an older version of my Django installation. However, I moved this to `~/GP_old` and moved a new Django installation to `~/GP` along with its associated `virtualenv` based on Python 3.5.x.

However, I noticed that the despite being in the `virtualenv` with the correct Python version, `python` still calls the 2.7.x version. Very strange.

Using `which` shows that despite being in the activated `virtualenv`, `python` refers to the system-wide version (2.7.x). Is the `virtualenv` bound to the location one created it in (in my case this was `~/GP_beta`)? If so, how do I update it?

I could delete the `virtualenv` and create a new version and reinstall my packages as well, but in some cases it seems smart to be able to fix it.

**Activating `virtualenv` and checking `python` version:**

```
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP $ source env/bin/activate
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

**Verifying the version in the `virtualenv` is actually the correct one:**

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP $ cd env/bin
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/env/bin $ ls -la
total 3736
drwxr-xr-x 3 mint mint    4096 Aug  8 05:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 mint mint    4096 Aug  8 05:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mint mint    2081 Aug  8 05:53 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 mint mint    1023 Aug  8 05:53 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 mint mint    2221 Aug  8 05:53 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 mint mint    1137 Aug  8 05:53 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     286 Aug  8 05:53 django-admin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     145 Aug  8 05:53 django-admin.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     253 Aug  8 05:53 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     253 Aug  8 05:53 easy_install-3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     225 Aug  8 05:53 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     225 Aug  8 05:53 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     225 Aug  8 05:53 pip3.5
drwxr-xr-x 2 mint mint    4096 Aug  8 05:53 __pycache__
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mint mint       9 Aug  8 05:53 python -> python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mint mint       9 Aug  8 05:53 python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint 3759688 Aug  8 05:53 python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint    2340 Aug  8 05:53 python-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mint mint     232 Aug  8 05:53 wheel
```

**Which python installation does `python` point to?**

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/env/bin $ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I believe that when you move a new virtualenv into position like this, it must have exactly the same path as the old one. i.e., GP_beta might be embedded somewhere in a pathname in virtualenv and could be the problem.

Comment: You seem to be right. `virtualenv` apparently uses absolute paths by default and thus break when moved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it

I voted to close as duplicate. The solution by http://stackoverflow.com/a/16683703/3980197 worked for me.