# Python system libraries leak into virtual environment

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

While working on a new python project and trying to learn my way through virtual environments, I've stumbled twice with the following problem:

- I create my virtual environment called venv. Running `pip freeze` shows nothing.
- I install my dependencies using pip install dependency. the venv library starts to populate, as confirmed by pip freeze.
- After a couple of days, I go back to my project, and after activating the virtual environment via `source venv/bin/activate`, when running pip freeze I see the whole list of libraries installed in the system python distribution (I'm using Mac Os 10.9.5), instead of the small subset I wanted to keep inside my virtual environment.

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong in between, but I have no idea how could this happen. Any ideas?

---

Update:
after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33366748/3294665) answer, I realized the that when running `pip freeze`, the `pip` command that's being invoked is the one at `/usr/local/bin/pip` instead of the one inside my virtual environment. So the virtual environment is fine, but I wonder what changes in the path might be causing this, and how to prevent them to happen again (my PYTHONPATH variable is not set).

Comment: If you used mkvirtualenv command it supports no-site-packages option.

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi but the problem doesn't exist at first... only about a week or so I've encountered this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my problem arose when moving my virtual environment folder around the system. The fix was to modify the `activate` and `pip` scripts located inside the `venv/bin` folder to point to the new venv location, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683703/3294665) answer. Now my pip freeze is showing the right files.