# Permission error when installing Django within virtual environment

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I have Django 1.10 installed within a virtualenv on my machine. Now I am creating another virtualenv (for another project) and installing Django 1.11 on it using the following command:

```
pip install Django
```

but I get a permission denied error:

```
Collecting Django
  Using cached Django-1.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Django)
Installing collected packages: Django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 377, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/__pycache__/django-admin.cpython-35.pyc'
```

I have read multiple SO posts about this but their solutions dont seem to apply to me. Please note:

1) I have *already activated* the new virtualenv before running the command.

2) I *did not* create the new virtualenv using sudo. I just did the following to create it:

`virtualenv name-of-the-new-virtualenv`

What could I be missing?

Comment: What are the results of running `which pip` and `which python` after sourcing the virtualenv you're trying to install Django into? Also, what does your VIRTUAL_ENV and PATH look like (`echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"` and `echo "$PATH"`)?

Comment: Brandon, you solved the problem. `which pip` and `which python` returned system paths and not the virtualenv paths. Then  `echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"` returned a path that did not exist! I had actually moved the virtualenv directory to home directory from project directory to keep all virtualenv directories at the same place (I think I read somewhere that we can move them around but looks like that was not a good idea). I moved it back and it worked fine. Feel free to write an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. I answered with some additional general information about virtualenvs to help future onlookers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using bash, the version of python being resolved in the `PATH` can be seen at any time by using `which python`.

You can also check the location of your sourced virtualenv by viewing the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable (e.g. `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`).

**In this case, the issue was that the virtualenv directory had been moved after being created**, so the `PATH` environment variable wasn't getting populated with the virtualenv's correct `bin` directory upon sourcing. One solution for moving a virtualenv is to make it "relocatable", which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628642/5221054).

Virtualenvs can be activated by sourcing the `activate` script:

```
source /path/to/my/venv/bin/activate
```

When any virtualenv has been sourced, it can be deactivated by using the `deactivate` function:

```
deactivate
```