# virtualenv activation doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I've created a virtual environment with:

```
$ virtualenv my_ven_test
```

then let's activate the environment with:

```
$ source my_ven_test/bin/activate
```

now let's install a package:

```
(my_ven_test) $ pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3
```

This last line does not take effect. In fact if I check:

```
(my_ven_test) $ pip freeze
```

I see no package installed (as well as the `my_ven_test/lib/python/site-package` directory doesn't contain the mysql-connector package)

Could you guide me in solving this issue?

Some notes:

- python version: 2.7
- virtualenv version: 15.1.0

Comment: this is `(my_ven_test) $ pip freeze` right?

Comment: yes, it is. i've modified the post. thanks

Comment: Did you move/rename your venv after creating it? If so, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it) may shed some light on the issue. May be useful to check that the output of `which pip` points to the `pip` executable in the virtualenv directory. If not, you may have issues with your PATH enviroment variable.

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $PATH`, from virtualenv?

Comment: Did you already upgraded pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: @AlejandroBR yes requirements already up-to-date

Comment: @heemayl this is the output /home/hadoop/my_ven_test/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin

Comment: is the path in the first line of `my_ven_test/bin/pip` pointing to the correct python? then, is the path in `my_ven_test/bin/activate` line 42 or so the correct path to your virtualenv? if you moved your virtualenv, move it back to where you created it and run `virtualenv --relocatable my_ven_test`, then you can move it again.

Comment: @jojo yes to both. I didn't move the virtualenv

Comment: PATH looks OK to me... Is it possible that you installed pip *after* creating the virtualenv? Check that the `pip` executable is actually present in the venv's `/bin` directory. If it's in there, then the output of `which pip` should be like `/home/hadoop/my_ven_test/bin/pip` I would recommend, for sanity's sake, trying to create another virtualenv and see if you're still getting the same problem. Keep in mind you don't want to rename/move your venv after creating it.

Comment: @sytech already checked. all things seems ok (there was no installation after the creation of virtualenv)

Comment: did `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3` execute without errors? when I run it in a new venv it fails.

Comment: @jojo executed without errors. keep in mind that this is only a test. you can use pip install numpy as well

Comment: :P i ran install numpy first with expected behavior and showing up in a `freeze`. To me there is no flaw apparent in your setup, thus my question.

Comment: I always just run `python -m pip`, since I typically have numerous Python installs and virtualenvs. `pip` should work out of the box, but manually specifying the Python interpreter should **always** work.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh no difference with python -m pip

Comment: `mysql-connector` doesn't create `mysql-connector` in `site-packages`, it creates `mysql` and `mysqlx` directories plus `_mysql_connector.so` and `_mysqlxpb.so` libraries. Try `pip show mysql-connector`.

Comment: @phd I have no output with `pip show mysql-connector`. Same thing if I type `pip install pandas`. `mysql-connector` is just an example

Comment: Someone suggested looking at the output of `which pip`, and I don't see that here. After you activate your venv, what do you get from `which pip`, `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`, and `pwd`?

Comment: Oh, here's another question: does this happen with any virtual environment you create, or is it just this one?

Comment: I would also request output for `pip -V` and `python -V`  inside the venv. Not enough info provided in question. Also, a log from `pip install somepkg -vvv` is often helpful.

Comment: Please provide console outpur of `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forget about `virtualenv`, use the brand new [**`Pipenv`**](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) which is [recommended by **Python.org**](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#installing-pipenv)

---

[**`Pipenv`**](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) automatically creates and manages a *virtualenv* for your projects, as well as adds/removes packages from your `Pipfile` (more about this below) as you install/uninstall packages.

---

First install [**pipenv**](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) using:

```
$ pip install pipenv
```

Then, for installing project specific packages, first create your project folder and then install all necessary packages for your project like:

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject

# install `requests` library
$ pipenv install requests

# install more libraries required for your project
$ pipenv install mysql-connector
$ pipenv install numpy
```

This will create two files, namely `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. You can find the list of *all* installed packages for the current project in the file `Pipfile` while `Pipfile.lock` has info on hashes like `sha256` for all the installed packages and their dependencies.

---

Once you're done with the installation of all necessary packages for your project, then do:

```
$ pipenv shell
```

which will launch a subshell in *virtual environment*. (This does the similar job of *source  /your/virtualenv/activate*)

Then you can start coding.. For example, you can first test whether installed packages are working fine by launching a Python shell and import the packages like below:

```
$ python
>>> import requests
# ....
```

---

To exit out of the (virtualenv) shell, simply do:

```
$ exit
```

Now, you're out of the virtual environment created by [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/)

Read more about it [installing packages for your project @ pipenv.kennethreitz.org](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project)

Comment: I found this intriguing.  Unfortunatly, with any (new or existing) project I get this - `pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp13ba53__build/mysqlclient/`.  What paths exactly is this looking for requirements.txt?  It says it finds requirements.txt even in a completely empty folder.

Comment: @Jaberwocky Sure!! try checking it with `pipenv lock -r` to get a requirements.txt file.

Comment: I don't want one.  I want to prevent `pipenv install` from "automatically detecting" one.  It's seeing a requirements.txt when run from an empty folder.

Comment: @Jaberwocky that's strange. Maybe you can report the issue here: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues

Answer (score 1):

When you are within a venv you should use the following to install a package:

```
py -m pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3
```

the -m ensures the package is installed into your venv and not into your root python

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package without activating virtualenv:

```
# Install it
my_ven_test/bin/pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3
# Use grep to check if exists
my_ven_test/bin/pip list | grep mysql-connector
```

If that works, then try to activate virtualenv by running this code:

```
. my_ven_test/bin/activate
```

Try installing another package

```
pip install flake8
```

Afterwards, search for those two packages

```
pip list | grep mysql-connector
pip list | grep flake8
```

Let me know the result.

Answer (score -1):

after jumping to Scripts folder cd Scripts just write .\activate It works perfectly
[see here on youtube](https://youtu.be/dA4sxEyvA1Y)