# ImportError after changing the top level directory name

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, flask, sublimetext2

I changed the top level directory name on a project, and now I'm getting an import error for Flask:

`ImportError: No module named flask`

The virtual environment is active - so unless there's something broken in its settings, that's not the problem.

I thought the error was because my path had changed, so in Sublime Text 2 I corrected the path name in the project's `.sublime-project` file to reflect the new top level directory name. However, this doesn't seem to have worked, or it is insufficient, as I'm still getting errors. Where else might I need to address this path change to get things working again, or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is actually a virtualenv question that has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it).

Comment: Turns out, I'd fixed everything and simply needed to shut down the virtual environment and sublime and restart everything. Works fine now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it)