# Where should virtualenvs be created?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm confused as to where I should put my virtualenvs.

With my first django project, I created the project with the command

```
django-admin.py startproject djangoproject
```

I then cd'd into the djangoproject directory and ran the command

```
virtualenv env
```

which created the virtual environment directory at the same level as the inner `djangoproject` directory.

Is this the wrong place in which to create the virtualenv for this particular project?

I'm getting the impression that most people keep all their virtualenvs together in an entirely different directory, e.g. `~/virtualenvs`, and then use virtualenvwrapper to switch back and forth between them.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: On windows, I personally create an extra directory under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mypythonenvs\``. For example I create 
 `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mypythonenvs\python3-qiskit` for a Qiskit env. This way I don't have to worry about forgetting path after 2 months.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Many people use the [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) tool, which keeps all virtualenvs in the same place (the `~/.virtualenvs` directory) and allows shortcuts for creating and keeping them there. For example, you might do:

```
mkvirtualenv djangoproject
```

and then later:

```
workon djangoproject
```

It's probably a bad idea to keep the virtualenv directory in the project itself, since you don't want to distribute it (it might be specific to your computer or operating system). Instead, keep a requirements.txt file using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and distribute that. This will allow others using your project to reinstall all the same requirements into their virtualenv with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: nice I hadnt ever looked into the pip stuff but if i need to some day this will come in handy

Comment: pip is very popular in the Django community and very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks David, that's kind of what I thought.  I knew about the requirements thing and am doing that.  I just wasn't sure about where the venv should go.  Your comment about it being OS-specific is a good justification for doing what you suggest.

Comment: Is it possible to move a virtual environment after it has been created? I un-wittingly put it inside of my project directory

Comment: Not a great justification IMO. Isn't this what .gitignore is for?

Comment: @JoshNoe isn't .gitignore the thing you normally forget and your repo explodes and credentials end up on github? ;)

Comment: *"It's probably a bad idea to keep the virtualenv directory in the project itself, since you don't want to distribute it"... but many existing package managers for other languages do exactly that (e.g. Rust/cargo, Haskell/stack/cabal, JS/npm).

Answer (score 41):

**Changing the location of the virtualenv directory breaks it**

This is one advantage of putting the directory outside of the repository tree, e.g. under `~/.virtualenvs` with `virutalenvwrapper`.

Otherwise, if you keep it in the project tree, moving the project location will break the virtualenv.

See: [Renaming a virtualenv folder without breaking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628476/renaming-a-virtualenv-folder-without-breaking-it)

There is `--relocatable` but it is known to not be perfect.

Another minor advantage: you don't have to `.gitignore` it.

The advantages of putting it gitignored in the project tree itself are:

- keeps related stuff close together.
- you will likely never reuse a given virtualenv across projects, so putting it somewhere else does not give much advantage

This is an annoying design flaw in my opinion. They should implement virutalenv in a way that does not matter where the directory is, as storing in-tree is just simpler and more isolated. Node.js' NPM package manager does it without any problem. And while we are at it: pip should just use local directories by default just like NPM. Having this separate  virtualenv layer is wonky. Node.js just have NPM that does it all without extra typing. I can't believe I'm prasing the JavaScript ecosystem on a Python post, but it's true.

Comment: This is the only reasonable argument I've seen for creating virtualenv folders outside of project trees! Other guideance just seems to repeat 'centralization' dogma as if it were inherently a best practice instead of an unfortunate compromise due to virtualenvs being fundamentally broken (albeit quite useful!).

Comment: Sorry something is not clear to me, so are you recommending creating it in the project tree and then"gitignoring" it or creating it in the ~/.virtualenvs ? What does "If it weren't for that" refer to?

Comment: @aderchox there's a tradeoff: put it into project tree and it tree moves you have to reinstall, or put it on ~ but manage on extra subdir outside of project.

Comment: Yet another in the long line of annoying design flaws and bad decisions in Python. Python 2/3 is another. I'm trying to use multiple Python applications, not develop them, and there is no better recommendation I can find than "create a brand new directory per application and create a venv in there."

Comment: @Cliff yes. Python is a bit old. By the time people understood that Node and Ruby had the correct package management, Python political power was already too decentralized to make changes fast. Things are improving slowly I think.

Answer (score 7):

The generally accepted place to put them is the same place that the default installation of virtualenvwrapper puts them: `~/.virtualenvs`

Related: virtualenvwrapper is an excellent tool that provides shorthands for the common virtualenv commands. http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Answer (score 2):

If you use `pyenv install Python`, then [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) will be a best practice. If set `.python-version` file, it can auto activate or deactivate virtual env when you change work folder. `Pyenv-virtualenv` also put all virtual env into `$HOME/.pyenv/versions` folder.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience, I would recommend to organize all virtual environments in one single directory. Unless someone has extremely sharp memory and can remember files/folders scattered across file system.
Not a big fan of using other tools just to mange virtual environments. In VSCode if I configure(`python.venvPath`) directory containing all virtual environments, it can automatically recognize all of them.

Comment: I don't think a sharp memory is necessary. If my virtual environments remain in my project directories, I already know where to find them.

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda installations of Python, the "conda create" command puts it in a directory within the anaconda3 folder by default. Specifically (for Windows):

C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs

This allows other conda commands to work without specifying the path. One advantage, not noted above, is that putting environments in the project folder allows you to use the same name for all of them (but that is not much of an advantage for me). For more info, see:
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html