# How does a Python command like "pserve" determine which virtual environment to run from?

Tags: python, python-venv, virtual-environment

I'm using Windows.

I successfully ran the following command in command prompt:

```
C:\projects\quick_tutorial\env\Scripts\cc_starter>pserve development.ini --reload
```

The `pserve` application can be found in at least 2 locations on my machine:

1. `C:\projects\quick_tutorial\env\Scripts`
2. `C:\Python34\Scripts`

**Questions:**

1. I ran `pserve` from a folder that doesn't contain the `pserve` application. How is it determined which `pserve` should start the `development.ini` file?
2. How is it determined which Python module / environment should be used to run my "cc_starter" project? I'm confused, because I read here: [Where should virtualenvs be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184846/where-should-virtualenvs-be-created) that it doesn't matter where virtual environments are created; so is it the location of the `pserve` application that determines the virtual environment used to run my project? or a command line within one of the files in my "cc_starter" project?

For reference, I'm following the [Quick Tutorial for Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/cookiecutters.html)

Comment: If you are using PowerShell, it looks like you can use "get-command pserve" to locate the application you used, like "which" command on Linux & Mac. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27140194/2644759

Comment: Thank you. I used: `\env\Scripts\cc_starter>where pserve` and only 1 location was returned: `C:\Python34\Scripts\pserve.exe`. I assume this means when I run pserve from the `\cc_starter location`, that it doesn't run the `pserve` app contained in the env directory. **Question:** Do I need to add `C:\projects\quick_tutorial\env` to my system variables to ensure that my project application and other apps like `pserve` run from within my virtual environment?

Comment: Well if you are using virtualenv you need to [`activate`](http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html#pymote-virtual-environment) it.