# Recommended workflow for cloning git into a virtual Python environment

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

What is the recommended workflow if I want to pull a git repo into a virtual Python environment? I *think* it's easiest to:

1. Create an empty directory
2. cd into it and `git clone <repo>`, as this will work only in empty directories
3. create the virtual environment in a subdir in the same directory
4. Start the VE and install requirements.txt from the `<repo>`.
5. Add the subdir (and other stuff for my eyes only) to .gitignore
6. work on project as intended
7. perhaps ask to push valuable/shareable results to the original repo.

Or is there a better way?

Disclaimer: I'm quite a n00b with git, please bear with me. I'm well aware there are multiple similar answers already, however I couldn't find a convincing TL;DR. Perhaps I missed it.

Comment: What is the purpose to add VE into git? I assume requirements.txt should be enough usually.

Comment: @Chuan The VE isolates the project, ie the clone. In the VE, I have no more, no more, no less, than what's in its requirements.txt. I also have a 'global' Python dev environment (several, in fact) that may have different versions of the libraries required for the clone.

Comment: Sure, understand. But VE should not be added into git IMHO, it should only be used to isolate the working env as you mentioned.

Comment: @Chuan I see what you mean. You have the VE outside the clone, right? That means more typing (more typo's). I like to keep things as short as possible. I guess it's a matter of taste

Comment: FYI, I usually use virtualenvwrapper to manage all my VEs and never commit VEs into git

Comment: @Chuan thank you. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I like to do:

```
git clone <repo> <repodir>
cd <repodir>
virtualenv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

That's it.  Now any edits I make will be "live" in the virtual environment. I have a global `.gitignore` file (`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`) that includes `.venv`, so I don't need to update `.gitignore` in individual repositories.

Note that you don't need to run `git clone` in an empty directory. Because it creates a *new* directory, it doesn't care of the current directory is empty or not.

**Update**

Look, we're in a non-empty directory:

```
bash-4.4$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

We can run `git clone` here:

```
bash-4.4$ git clone https://github.com/git/git
Cloning into 'git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 264438, done.
remote: Total 264438 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 264438
Receiving objects: 100% (264438/264438), 112.69 MiB | 9.84 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (196057/196057), done.
```

It runs without a problem and creates a new directory:

```
bash-4.4$ ls
file1  file2  file3  git
```

Comment: Hmmm, git for windows won't let me git clone to the root of a drive 'because it is not empty'. Same for Linux git, I believe, see [here](https://www.itheo.nl/how-to-git-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory/) also.

Comment: No, that's absolutely not the same for Linux git.  You can't run `git init` in a non-empty directory, but `git clone` doesn't care (because, like I said, it will *create* a new subdirectory). I've added an example in the answer. I would be surprised to see that git under windows behaved any differently.

Comment: Windows: "This folder contains files. Git can only clone to empty folders". Here's a [screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ds3iN3EvH4eFCzXJ6) (I hope).

Comment: I see; you're not using the command line.  I can't comment on how the GUI operates, but it looks like in that case it is asking you to provide a directory into which it will place the cloned files (from the command line, that might look something like `git clone <repo> exisitingdir/`, in which  case, sure, the target must be empty. But that's generally not how one operates `git`.

Comment: The Windows GUI, when you enter the repo url e.g. `https://git/me/foo` and your default target dir is `Z:\`, it creates `Z:\foo` and clones into it. If you first create 
`Z:\foo` put a VE in it, then attempt to git clone alongside it, git refuses, for the aforementioned reason.

Comment: This works for me, apart from the final command: `pip install -e .` That requires either a `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file; the repo I'm cloning doesn't contain either. In my case, it was just a single library I needed to install which worked fine with the classic `pip install` route.

Answer (score 4):

If there's already an existing virtualenv for a project that you want to clone a library into to work with, the following steps will help you:

1. Activate the project's virtualenv
   `source .venv/bin/activate.fish`
2. Uninstall the package you want to have replaced with a git clone:
   `pip uninstall <package>`
3. Re-install the package via git:
   `pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.com/<org>/<package>.git#egg=<package>`
4. Change to package directory to work on the repository
   `cd .venv/src/<package>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am awared, it is not recommended to initialize and store your virtual environment in git directory of your project. In this case your env space is exposed to some kind of vulnarabilities. Among them:

1. If you remove your project directory, you lose your env. So there is no scalability to properly use it for other projects.
2. You need always keep in mind what is in `.gitignore` file in order to avoid unwanted distribution of your env.
3. I don't know any easy way to list all your envs with standard `python3-venv`. So, probably, if you operate like that, ocassionaly you will struggle to just find what available envs do you have.

Instead, recommended way is to use virtualenvwrapper tool, that is storing all envs in one specific directory, most commonly in `~/.virtualenvs`. This tool helps with creating, deleting and switching between your envs. See more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184846/where-should-virtualenvs-be-created).

With all said above, recommended workflow:

- install `virtualenvwrapper`
- create new env with `mkvirtualenv $env_name`
- initialize your rep with `git clone <rep>`
- run `pip install -r requirements.txt` under your `$env_name` environment