# Python - accidentally installed pip packages globally without creating a virtual env on Mac OS M1 Ventura - now what?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Total noob...I followed some instructions to install various programs from GitHub which didn't come with explanations on how virtualenv works and why it's best practice.

Now I understand via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184846/where-should-virtualenvs-be-created) that [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) in `~/.virtualenvs` is the way to go.

**What do I do now to clean up my global packages?**

Can I just leave them there and get on with my life?

I'm officially getting nowhere in my Python coding journey so far :P

(if it helps: I may have installed Python via Homebrew as well as their official [Downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) it's hard to remember if I did both or just one.)

Comment: `pip freeze` and then just `pip uninstall <package>`

Comment: You can do either of the options your listed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566052/11286032) tells you how to remove them or you can leave them if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe and Marcelo Paco! - I think I'll just leave them and cross my fingers I don't have conflicts later...

I will say, there are several dozens of packages, so it would be a real pain to uninstall them with the instructions ☝️ above

Comment: At worst, they are taking up space and *available* to your global Python installation, and you would want to install it again in your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in comments above:

Not dangerous to leave them.

Use [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566052/11286032) to remove the global packages in fancy way.

Or use the simple way: `pip freeze` then `pip uninstall <package>` to do manually one at a time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd suggest quoting the relevant command(s) from the linked answer to make it easier for future readers of this thread to find a solution. Reproducing the important parts from linked web-pages is considered good practice to avoid problems with dead-links.