# Where should I locate my Python file if I want to use virtualenv?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment and I do not know where should I save my Python file ? it only works when I run it in `/home/jojo/Enviroment/venv1` can I save it in other place ? Especially when I want to use PyCharm thank you

Comment: choose python version exists inside the virtual env through project settings -> interpreter

Comment: It worked!! thank YOU :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtualenv and your code base **can** very well be in different locations. I prefer things this way. Here are sample commands that I use.

**Step 1**: Activate the virtualenv.

```
[mayank@demo /dev]$ source /usr/local/pyenv3.4/bin/activate
(pyenv3.4)[mayank@demo dev]$
```

Notice the prefix "(pyenv3.4)" that indicates that virtualenv is now activated.

**Step 2**: Ensure that python executable in virtualenv is indeed pointed by "python"

```
(pyenv3.4)[mayank@demo dev]$ which python 
/usr/local/pyenv3.4/bin/python
```

Notice that python is indeed pointing to the one in virtualenv directory.

**Step 3**: Create a file elsewhere and execute it

```
echo "import sys; print(sys.executable)" > /tmp/print_python_exe.py
python /tmp/print_python_exe.py
```

Edit: As suggested by Paul, one might choose to keep the virtualenv directory inside the app directory. This style of structuring projects is also suggested here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#basic-usage

Comment: Thank YOU it worked, so if I use IDLE I have to run it through the terminal, right ?

Comment: You mean "IDE"? Pycharm allows to create or use and existing virtualenv for your projects.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: No I mean if I don't have PyCharm and I want to run Python in IDLE, do  have to run it through the terminal ?

Comment: Not sure. Never used IDLE. Let me redirect you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv. By the way, give a try to ipython. I use ipython extensively and know for the fact that it's powerful.

Comment: The code and the virtualenv do not *have* to be in different locations. I store my virtualenvs inside my projects. In fact, this is the pattern documented in the Python Packaging documentation.

Comment: I agree. I should drop the word "must" from my answer. This answer pretty much captures the gist : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785127/578989